# Count records in current week in symfony

Tags: symfony

I want count the records in current week. but I don't know how can i do this.

Here is my query:

```
$totalSearchesByUsersWeek = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('count(SearchHistory.id) AS totalSearchesByUsers')
    ->from('DRPAdminBundle:Log',  'SearchHistory')
    ->where('SearchHistory.last_updated like :last_updated')
    ->setParameter('last_updated',$week.'%')     
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

Please help

Comment: Current week meaning all the days starting of week 36 for example? Or just the past seven days?

Comment: current week means seven days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `between` with 2 `\DateTime` objects and your definition of the start and finish of the week. With `COUNT()` and `getSingleScalarResult` you would just get the single integer count as your result.

```
$start = new \DateTime();

// This will depend on which day you decide the week starts
if ('Monday' !== $start->format('l')) {
    // if week starts on Sunday you would just use (int) $start->format('w')
    $start->modify(sprintf('- %d days', (int) $start->format('w') - 1));
}

// clone the start date and add 6 days to get the end date
$end = clone($start);
$end->modify('+ 6 days');

// set the times to midnight for start and 1 second before midnight for finish
$start->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$end->setTime(23, 59, 59);

// for the date 2015-07-16 (today) this would result in
// start = 2015-07-13 00:00:00 (Monday)
// end   = 2015-07-19 23:59:59 (Sunday)

$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();

return $queryBuilder
    ->select('COUNT(o.id)')
    ->from('DRPAdminBundle:Log',  'o')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->between('o.last_updated', ':start', ':end'))
    ->setParameter('start', $start)
    ->setParameter('end', $end)     
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

**Also**

if you just wanted to get the last 7 days you could use..

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();

return $queryBuilder
    ->select('COUNT(o.id)')
    ->from('DRPAdminBundle:Log',  'o')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->gte('o.last_updated', ':start'))
    ->setParameter('start', new \DateTime('- 7 days'))
    ->getQuery()
    ->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `getArrayResult()` with `getSingleScalarResult()` and you will be good to go

Edit to answer your comment:

```
$totalSearchesByUsersWeek = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('SearchHistory.id AS totalSearchesByUsers')
->from('DRPAdminBundle:Log',  'SearchHistory')
->where('SearchHistory.last_updated like :last_updated')
->setParameter('last_updated',$week.'%')
->getQuery();

 $totalSearchesByUsersWeek->->getArrayResult(); //this will get you the array of id
```

and

```
 $totalSearchesByUsersWeek = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('count(SearchHistory.id) AS totalSearchesByUsers')
->from('DRPAdminBundle:Log',  'SearchHistory')
->where('SearchHistory.last_updated like :last_updated')
->setParameter('last_updated',$week.'%')
->getQuery();
 $totalSearchesByUsersWeek->->getSingleScalarResult(); //this will get you the COUNT of id
```

Edit2: replace your where clause with this

```
->where('SearchHistory.last_updated BETWEEN :monday AND :sunday')
->setParameter('monday', '2014-7-13')
->setParameter('sunday', '2014-7-19');  //or adjust date format accordingly
```

Comment: how can i get current week?

Comment: Bro I dont know how to ger current week means $week = ?

Comment: ok, that would depend on the database entry, what is the schema(columns and row values) of the  table 'last_updated' from database named 'SearchHistory'

Comment: last_updated is the column where all the dates are stored.